# How to automatically close command prompt when my ''Tool.bat'' has no activity anymore in cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file

How to automatically close command prompt when my ''Tool.bat'' finishes the job and no more activity there in or how to automatically kill a process who is no longer active but which still appears in: i open cmd.exe and type TASKLIST and is still there,thank you
P.S.
Need a command line to add to my ''tool.bat'' to close cmd.exe when has no activity anymore there o something to kill automatically the process oly when

Comment: If you run the batch file from Explorer, the console will close when the cmd instance that's executing it terminates as well as any child process that's attached to the same console. It will not close as long as there's a running process attached to it.

Comment: If you're running tool.bat from an existing cmd shell, then there's no reasonable basis to automatically kill the parent shell when your batch exits. You can do that yourself by running `tool.bat & exit`.

Comment: The command `exit` without parameter `/B` results always in exiting current command process independent on calling hierarchy. So you could put this command into `Tool.bat` at end to terminate the command process executing this batch file.

Comment: @Mofi, that's what the OP wants, but I think it's rarely something you'd want hard coded in the batch file itself. Scripts that kill your current shell would get annoying quickly.

Answer (score 0):

taskkill will terminate processes shown in task list. taskkill /? at command prompt for more info.